# Mysql Error 1442 When Updating a Related Table

Tags: mysql, triggers, database-trigger

I have two tables, Player and Answer. Answer has a list of response scores to specific questions and an identifying PlayerID, while Player should hold the total score and other information.

Here are my triggers:

```
CREATE TRIGGER answer_insert BEFORE INSERT ON Answer FOR EACH ROW
UPDATE Player SET Score = Score + New.Score
WHERE PlayerID = New.PlayerID;

CREATE TRIGGER answer_update BEFORE UPDATE ON Answer FOR EACH ROW
UPDATE Player SET Score = Score + (New.Score - Old.Score)
WHERE PlayerID = Old.PlayerID;
```

It creates them fine, but crashes my application when it comes time to do the update/insert. Am I doing something wrong?

Error message is:

Can't update table 'Player' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger

Comment: The error message indicates that the statement that causes the trigger to be fired is referencing the `Player` table. That's a documented restriction. We would expect that a statement that doesn't reference `Player` table e.g. `UPDATE Answer SET score = 2 WHERE playerid = 7;` would not throw an error. But when we add a JOIN to the Player into that statement, then we would expect the error.

Comment: Consider using *lowercase* for table names. From the MySQL Reference Manual...:  "it is best to adopt a consistent convention, such as always creating and referring to databases and tables using lowercase names. This convention is recommended for maximum portability and ease of use."  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html

Comment: Also, consider the edge case of an `UPDATE` statement changing the value of the `playerid` column in `answer` table.  e.g.  `UPDATE Answer SET PlayerID = 42 WHERE PlayerID = 7 AND ...`  If that modifies a row in `answer` table, what actions should be performed on which rows in the `player` table? Should we modify both rows in `player`, the one with playerid=7 as well as the one with playerid=42 ?

Comment: Thank you @spencer7593! I think I understand how this causes an issue now, but not exactly why it should. Regardless, is there another way to achieve the same functionality?